# Fragment reloads when switching

Tags: android

I am using fragment to display user information when switchCompat is on checked state ,and I am also opened an activity from fragment, when I goes back from activity to fragment  on programmer defind button click  ,fragent reloads again, and switchCompat goes off and user information gone.how to prevent fragment to reload again and  also show the user information when goes back activity to fragment.

Please help.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your code

Answer (score 0):

Use **sharedpreferences** to store the state of the switch.

I have created a method for you which will check the current state of switch and stores it in sharedpreferences

```
private void saveSwitchState() {
    switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("switchPref", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

            if (isChecked) {
                switchState = true;
                editor.putBoolean("SWITCH_STATE", switchState);
                editor.commit();
            } else {
                switchState = false;
                editor.putBoolean("SWITCH_STATE", switchState);
                editor.commit();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

you need to call this method on OnPause() and OnResume inside fragment. When you move to another activity or close the app the state of the switch gets stored in shared preferences

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    saveSwitchState();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    saveSwitchState();
}
```

now the state is saved, read SharedPreferences value on Oncreateview

```
    switch1 = (SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.switch_id);

    SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("switchPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(!prefs.equals(null)){
        switchState = prefs.getBoolean("SWITCH_STATE", false);
    }
    switch1.setChecked(switchState);
```